# Select Not returning results when an Update statement is running on the same row?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I have a table where it has columns as

### Task_Track

- TaskID Number (PK AutoGeneratedSequence)
- TaskCd Varchar2
- RefCd Varchar2
- RefID varchar2
- Params varchar2
- ...etc

I am working on a scenario where I run a select query on this table get the result set.

> Select * from Task_Track where RefCd = ? and RefID = ? and TaskCd = ?;

If i don't have any results I will insert a new task with RefCd RefID TaskCd Params values. Params is ususaly a person_id related to the task.
If i get the resultset I will append the new param and update the resultset.

> if(resultset!=null and resultSet.length()>0)
>
> update params logic
>
> else
>
> insert new task logic.

This is working as expected in a sequential run.
But when I have 2 parallel queues running and get the same RefCd RefID TaskCd values at the same time.
My first bucket is finding the resultset and is going to perform the update logic as expected but the second queue is not able to find the result and is going into insert logic.

From what I understand even if the first queue has locked the row for the update, the second queue should not have any problems with the read and should fail while updating because of the lock if the first queue hasn't released the lock. But my read itself is failing where it is not throwing any exception but returning an empty resultset(length=0). Because of which it is moving into insert logic.

Is it possible that the read is affected by the update happening in parallel? If so how should I resolve it?

Note: I am using Oracle 11G and Java8 with Websphere 9

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache the resultSet before make another request. Try this:

```
CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
crs.populate(myResultSet);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion. But the volume of data being processed is too much for much...right now in the testing scenario I am using 4000 Trigger Dump for the two parallel queues to do the processing but in real time the volume of Triggers can be more than 5-10times the current dump and i am not sure chaching those many resultsets is not ideal.

Comment: Hi @SitaramVuppala, can you get a different connection to execute the second query?

Comment: Hi, The two parallel queues have their own connections to the db...right now I am not controlling the connection to be the same for both queues